# Multiple worksheet filter, based on column header name

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I want to filter based on the value in the dropdown list. The code should look for that value based on the column header name, regardless of the position of the column header in each worksheet.

The solutions available assume each worksheet has the same layout whilst mine does not. The only constant is my column headers are in the same row (row 4). The column header names also remain the same although some contain more or less headers than other worksheets.

The code is a generic autofilter but assumes the columns are alike and each column to filter on is in the same spot on each worksheet.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Range("A2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Range("A2").Value = "" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").ShowAllData
        Else
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").AutoFilter 1, Range("A2").Value
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you basically need a dynamic reference for the column. Use something like this after your `Else` statement:

```
lastCol = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

Set headerRange = Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 1), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, lastCol)) 'range with all headers 

headerName = "your header" 'change to cell ref

matchCol = Application.Match(headerName, headerRange, 0) 'match for your header

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A4").AutoFilter matchCol, Range("A2").Value
```

I am assuming that your headers start at A4. This is also the cell that needs to be referenced in `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A4").AutoFilter` (not A2).